# how to find difference in dates in pandas dataframe in Azure ML

Tags: python, azure, pandas, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Is Azure uses some other Syntax for finding difference in dates and time.
or
Any package is missing in Azure.
how to find difference in dates in pandas data-frame in Azure ML.

I have 2 columns in a dataframe and I have to find the difference of two and have to kept in third column ,the problem is this, all this runs well in python IDE but not in Microsoft Azure.
My date format : `2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z`

 I have to to find df['days'] = `df['a'] - df['b']`
I have tried almost all the syntax available on stackoverflow.
Please help

```
mylist = ['app_lastCommunicatedAt', 'app_installAt', 'installationId']
```

```
'def finding_dates(df, mylist):
        for i in mylist:
            if i == 'installationId':
                continue
            df[i] = [pd.to_datetime(e) for e in df[i]]
        df['days'] = abs((df[mylist[1]] - df[mylist[0]]).dt.days)
        return df'
```

when I am calling this function it is giving error and not accepting lines below continue.

I had also tried many other things like converting dates to string, etc

Comment: impossible to answer without sample data, code, desired output and what the incorrect output is from your current code

Comment: provided some information will it help you to answer?

Comment: This converts fine to `Timestamp` in pandas: `In [167]:

2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z
pd.to_datetime('2015-09-25T01:45:34.372Z')
Out[167]:
Timestamp('2015-09-25 01:45:34.372000')` after conversion `df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])` you can do `df['days'] = (df['a'] - df['b']).dt.days`

Comment: this thing I had done in python IDE and it is working,but the same thing is not working in Azure.

Comment: You need to post the code and explain how it's not working

Comment: Could you post more details, such as exception information?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it seems that the issue was caused by your code without the `dataframe_service` which indicates that the function operations on a data frame, please see https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python#dataframe_service. If not being familiar with the decorator `@`, please see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/ to know it.